# Training loop doesn't start when num_workers >1 in the DataLoader

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, cpu-usage, training-data, pytorch-dataloader

I have an NLP classification problem where I have a DataLoader object and its code is

```
train_patentload = DataLoader(train_patentset, batch_size=4, shuffle=True,num_workers=2)
```

When I run the training loop it doesn't work and gets stuck though the code runs normally when num_workers=2 is removed. I have been stuck for a while now and I'd appreciate the help

the code of the DataSet

```py
class PatentDataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, df):
        self.df= df

    def __len__(self):
        return len(df)

    def __getitem__(self, ind):
        conv_dict = {0 : [1., 0., 0., 0., 0.], 0.25 : [1., 1., 0., 0., 0.], 0.5 : [1., 1., 1., 0., 0.], 0.75 : [1., 1., 1., 1., 0.], 1 : [1., 1., 1., 1., 1.]}
        inputs = df.iloc[ind, 1:-1].to_list()
        text = ' #^& '.join(inputs)
        label = np.array(conv_dict[df.iloc[ind, -1]])
        label = torch.as_tensor(label)
        text = tokenizer(text, padding='max_length', max_length = 256, truncation=True, return_tensors="pt")
        return text, label

train_patentset = PatentDataset(train)
```

where train is the dataframe.

Comment: The code contains error. You use df inside class methods but it should be self.df, you are missing the call to the parent class in the init. It is unclear where the tokenizer comes from, what it is. When I try a minimal example, with a dataframe with some random data it works for me, with any number of workers.

Answer (score 0):

Num workers 2 causes pytorch to spawn 2 processes via multiprocessing. Both processes then have their own instance of the train_patentset. If you omit the num_worker it is set to 0 which means the data loading is done in the main thread/process.

Since you did not post more code the only advise is to look through the code of your dataset and see if there are points which are not save for multi processing. Do you somehow use information from outside the dataset class, rely on communication via variables or something.

Best would be to update the question and include the code for the dataset.

Comment: Thank you! I edited the question with the dataset code, Have a look and tell me what u find out if you have the time.